# GPUImageMotionBlurFilter and images with transparency

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm trying to apply `GPUImageMotionBlurFilter` to a snapshot of `UIView`. I want to blur the top and bottom edges of the view too, so I'm leaving a transparent space (`insetY`) above and below the rect passed to `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`. GPUImage seems to ignore the transparency and acts like it was filled with a color a little lighter than `-lightGrayColor`.

Here's my code (it's in a method in `UIView` subclass):

```
CGFloat insetX = 0;
CGFloat insetY = 10;
CGRect snapshotFrame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, -insetX, -insetY);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(snapshotFrame.size, NO, 0.0f);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(insetX, insetY, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

GPUImageMotionBlurFilter *motionBlurFilter = [[GPUImageMotionBlurFilter alloc] init];
motionBlurFilter.blurAngle = 90;
motionBlurFilter.blurSize = 20.0f;

UIImage *blurredImage = [motionBlurFilter imageByFilteringImage:snapshotImage];
```

And here's what I'm getting:

`snapshotImage`:

[image]

`blurredImage`:

[image]

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: That looks like an issue with precalculated alpha. A blur filter like this calculates the blur based on each RGBA channel separately, so the alpha is independent of the other colors. If your transparent area had a black RGB value, it would appear grey like this when blended with the other colors. Does this still appear grey when blended over a white background with an alpha-respecting blend, not just in QuickLook?

Comment: It looks exactly the same when shown in `UIImageView` over a white background; I'm not sure if you meant that, but that's what I'm trying to achieve. I saved `blurredImage` to a file with `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, maybe it'll be useful to you: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5184129/SO/blurredImage_from_app.png Also, `blurredImage` looks the same if the background is first filled (using `CGContextFillRect`) with either black or white (both with alpha = 0.0).

Comment: Can you make the RGB values of your transparent areas the same pinkish color as the background for your image? It looks like the RGB values for those areas are black, or are being pulled in as black. The blend is then using that black for the color of your transparent areas, darkening your image when it's blended. Again, I'm handling each color channel independently for the blur, so it's using the RGB values for your transparent area in those calculations.

Comment: @BradLarson: I tried setting transparent areas to: `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.886 green:0.847 blue:0.812 alpha:0.0]`, but the output was the same as before. Fill was applied correctly, because I also tried it with alpha set to 1. Just to make sure we're on the same page, here's what I'm trying to achieve: from [input](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5184129/SO/input.png) to [output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5184129/SO/output.png) (screenshots are from Pixelmator).

Comment: @BradLarson: here's the output image with increased insets: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5184129/SO/blurredImage1404299682.png It's easier to see here how the blur fades away.

Comment: This same problem has affected other image processing libraries as well. Here's the page on ImageMagick explaining what they recommend to fix it (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/bugs/blur_trans/). A filter (or a toggle for the existing one) to account for transparency would be ideal, @BradLarson. Thanks so much for the library, it makes a lot of things so much easier.